# Is it possible to select data in the post save BADI of a deletion?

Tags: abap, sap-r3

I am using Badi `MD_PLDORD_POST` when I delete an order using transaction `MF50`.

I want to retrieve data that is not available in the parameters of the `IF_EX_MD_PLDORD_POST~POST_AFTER_SAVE_MAN` method.

I tried using `BYPASSING BUFFER`:

```
SELECT SINGLE plnum
      FROM plaf
      INTO @DATA(lv_plnum)
      BYPASSING BUFFER
      WHERE plnum = @im_plaf_new-plnum.
```

It does not find any data, but if I but a break on the select and check the data in `SE11`, table `PLAF` - the entry is there.

This select works when the order is being created or edited, so it is not a conversion problem.

Is it impossible the get the data at this point (if so, then why is the data still visible in `SE11` at that point ?) , or am I using the `BYPASSING BUFFER` wrong ?

Comment: `AFTER_SAVE_` doesn't mean it had been committed, so you are using BYPASSING BUFFER wrong. You should use simple SELECT here, check also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429331/reading-original-before-change-db-values-in-the-current-luw

Comment: Using 'CONNECTION r/3*my_conn' in the select statement worked ! (I also removed BYPASSING BUFFER from the statement)

Comment: so post this as answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CONNECTION r/3*my_conn` in the select statement worked!

I also removed `BYPASSING BUFFER` from the statement:

```
SELECT SINGLE plnum
      FROM plaf
      INTO @DATA(lv_plnum)
      CONNECTION r/3*my_conn
      WHERE plnum = @im_plaf_new-plnum.
```